# Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (400) low level call on DELETE:

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

A delete request making with the Elasticsearch NEST client is encountering an issue - Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (400) low level call on DELETE:

Code: C#

```
        var client = await ConnectClient().ConfigureAwait(true);

        DeleteResponse deleteResponse = null;

        foreach (var eventTimeSlotsId in eventTimeSlotsIds)
        {
            deleteResponse = client.Delete<dynamic>(eventTimeSlotsId, d => d.Index(_indexName).Routing(new Routing(routing: productId.ToString())));
        }

        return deleteResponse;
```

Here the eventTimeSlotsIds is list of GUID ids and productId is also GUID

expecting a successful deletion.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please verify that you establish a connection to your elastic search ? This can be easily done if after `var client = ...` , you execute `var pingResponse = client.Ping();
` and check afterwards `pingResponse.IsValid`. If it is true, then you establish a connection with elastic search. If not, then sth is going wrong with establishing the connection with elastic search.

Comment: Could you please include details from deleteResponse.DebugInformation?